# When subclassing ndarray why does a transpose happen after __array_finalize__ and not before?

Tags: python, numpy, subclassing

Let us for simplicity just copy the diagnostic ndarray subclass from the numpy docs:

```
import numpy as np

class MySubClass(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.info = info
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        print('In __array_finalize__:')
        print('   self is %s' % repr(self))
        print('   obj is %s' % repr(obj))
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)
```

Now let's do a simple example:

```
>>> x = MySubClass(np.ones((1,5)))
In __array_finalize__:
   self is MySubClass([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
   obj is array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
>>> y = x.T
In __array_finalize__:
   self is MySubClass([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
   obj is MySubClass([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

As we can see something that clearly isn't the transpose is passed to `__array_finalize__`. Apart from stretching the meaning of the word "finalize" to entire new realms, what is the purpose of this behavior?

Wouldn't it make more sense to send the actual output, i.e. the transpose through this hook for it to be finalized?

What is the recommended way to touch up the base transpose with whatever postprocessing my subclass might require?

Comment: Just to be clear, `y` is still the transpose of `x`, with `info` set as intended.  In my own testing, some methods apparently call `finalize` before making changes (like this transpose), but for others `self` has already been changed (e.g. indexing)

Comment: Apparently `finalize` is called when the instance is created (via `new/init` or some sort of `view`), but some some processing, like transpose, is applied after.  `ufunc` appear to create an `empty` of the right subclass, shape and dtype, and use that as the `out`, assigning values after `finalize`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because for creating the new object they rely on the already available (common) function [`PyArray_NewFromDescrAndBase`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/0b9b176dcef7f14f56dbd543c89e6da6c6b7b2e4/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L1194) to handle the memory allocation. The source code of [`PyArray_Transpose`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/0b9b176dcef7f14f56dbd543c89e6da6c6b7b2e4/numpy/core/src/multiarray/shape.c#L707) reveals that first the new object is created from the existing array, with similar shape and strides, and then those are corrected by accessing the previously allocated memory:

```
/*
 * this allocates memory for dimensions and strides (but fills them
 * incorrectly), sets up descr, and points data at PyArray_DATA(ap).
 */
Py_INCREF(PyArray_DESCR(ap));
ret = (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_NewFromDescrAndBase(
        Py_TYPE(ap), PyArray_DESCR(ap),
        n, PyArray_DIMS(ap), NULL, PyArray_DATA(ap),
        flags, (PyObject *)ap, (PyObject *)ap);
if (ret == NULL) {
    return NULL;
}

/* fix the dimensions and strides of the return-array */
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    PyArray_DIMS(ret)[i] = PyArray_DIMS(ap)[permutation[i]];
    PyArray_STRIDES(ret)[i] = PyArray_STRIDES(ap)[permutation[i]];
}
```

Here `PyArray_NewFromDescrAndBase` is responsible for [invoking `__array_finalize__`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/0b9b176dcef7f14f56dbd543c89e6da6c6b7b2e4/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L1126) and hence that method receives the version with incorrect shape and strides (i.e. non-transposed). It would be possible to do differently but it would require an extra parameter for `PyArray_NewFromDescrAndBase` to defer the call to `__array_finalize__` and then it could be done manually after the shape and strides have been adjusted.

Comment: Thanks. `PyArray_NewFromDescrAndBase` appears to take a`dims` and a `strides` argument, so it would be rather easy to transpose before calling it, right?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Indeed it seems that would be a possibility. But it would require allocating memory beforehand which the current solution circumvents. Maybe nobody thought about the interaction with `__array_finalize__` (which was perhaps introduced later, though I couldn't find definitive dates using `git blame`), and the current version seemed to be a straightforward solution.