# Why does numpy.resize() have a base object that is not the original object?

Tags: python, numpy

I have recently switched from using `np.ndarray.resize()` to `np.resize()`. What concerns me is that using the latter, the resulting array has a base object that I cannot explain. Can someone please explain this to me?

Note that I understand the differences due to references and `refcheck`. The code does not have any references to the object other than `a`; I switched to `np.resize()` so that PyCharm/iPython would not complain since they hold additional references.

The former:

```py
>>> a = np.arange(5)
>>> a.resize(10)
>>> a.base is None
True
```

The latter:

```py
>>> a = np.arange(5)
>>> b = a
>>> a = np.resize(a, 10)
>>> a.base
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.base is a, a.base is b
(False, False)
```

Comment: I haven't explored them in depth, but my sense is that they are fundamentally different.  One replicates values to the new spaces, the other zero fills.  But why are you using them at all?  Creating arrays with `np.zeros` etc, indexing, reshaping, and so on is usually enough.

Comment: @hpaulj "But why are you using them at all?" -- a good question which will lead me to any number of workarounds such as preallocate-and-fill or any of the various flavors of `np.append()`. However, my question was about the `base` object I cannot explain when using `np.resize()`.

Comment: Looking at the `.__array_interface__` I don't think `np.resize` uses the same memory buffer.  The method operates in-place, The function does not

Comment: @hpaulj, that is perfectly understandable, and the docs say the same thing about in-place vs. new object, but why would there be a `base` object? And why would it not be the same as the new object? Or is this just an implementation detail that should not concern a user like me?

Comment: Loosely related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60774884/7207392 another instance of numpy devs not placing high priority on returning clean new objects.